# Convert MAC Address Format

Tags: php, regex, formatting, mac-address

I just wrote a small script to pull hundreds of MAC Addresses from a switch for comparison, however they are formatted as "0025.9073.3014" rather than the standard "00:25:90:73:30:14".

I am stumped on how to convert this, where the best I can come up with is exploding these into pieces at the ".", then breaking them down further into 2 pieces each, then rejoin all parts with ":" separators.

I am okay with hacky methods but this is bothering me because that is a very poor approach. Is there any way to perform this better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A combination of `str_replace` and `preg_replace`:

```
$str = preg_replace('~..(?!$)~', '\0:', str_replace(".", "", $str));
```

First stripping out the `.` then adding `:` after `..` two of any characters `(?!$)` if not at the end.

[Test at eval.in](https://eval.in/201445)

---

Or use a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and do it without str_replace:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(..)(?!$)\.?~', '\1:', $str);
```

[Test at regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/eW4mP3/1)

There's not much difference in performance.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like regular expressions, then here's another method of doing it, which is more understandable, if you're new to PHP. Basically, it just removes the dots, and then splits the string into an array after every 2 characters, then implodes them with a colon:

```
$string = "0025.9073.3014";
$result = implode(":", str_split(str_replace(".", "", $string), 2));
echo $result;
```

Outputs:

> 00:25:90:73:30:14

Answer (score 2):

Using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with [capturing groups, backreferences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php):

```
$mac = "0025.9073.3014";
$mac = preg_replace('/(..)(..)\.(..)(..)\.(..)(..)/',
                    '$1:$2:$3:$4:$5:$6', $mac);
echo($mac);
// => 00:25:90:73:30:14
```

Comment: Oddly this only worked on that specific MAC Address and failed on others but thanks for the example!

Comment: @BrettPowell, I should have used `.` instead of `\d` because mac address contains hexadecimal. I updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if the mac address is constant in this format.

```
$str = '0025.9073.3014';
$str = preg_replace('~\d+\K(?=\d\d)|\.~', ':', $str);
echo $str; //=> "00:25:90:73:30:14"
```

Answer (score 0):

This universal function uses [sscanf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) to parse the string and [vsprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) to format the output.

```
function formatMac($string,$formatInput,$formatOutput)
{
  return vsprintf($formatOutput,sscanf($string,$formatInput));
}
```

Examples of usage:

```
$string = "0025.9073.3014";
echo formatMac($string,'%02s%02s.%02s%02s.%02s%02s','%02s:%02s:%02s:%02s:%02s:%02s');
//00:25:90:73:30:14

$string = '00:a0:3d:08:ef:63';
echo formatMac($string,'%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x','%02X%02X%02X:%02X%02X%02X');
//00A03D:08EF63

$string = '00A03D:08EF63';
echo formatMac($string,'%02X%02X%02X:%02X%02X%02X','%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x');
//00:a0:3d:08:ef:63
```